# Object reference not set to an instance of an object EDIT

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm new here and I tried looking through old questions but I am new to c# as well, and I am finding it difficult to solve my problem below:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\ESC\Impostazioni.txt"))
{
    TextReader lettore_file = new StreamReader(@"C:\ESC\Impostazioni.txt");
    String opzioni = lettore_file.ReadLine();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < opzioni.Length; i++) <----here, indicating "i=0"
    {
        if (opzioni[i] == '-')
        {
             char[] coloregenerale = new char[i];
             for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
               coloregenerale[j] = opzioni[j];

           break;
```

Comment: What is the value of `opzioni`? I'm going to bet it is `null`.

Comment: If the EOF is on the first line your `ReadLine` will return `null`. Be sure your file exists and contains text.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and debugging through the code to pinpoint where exactly it is failing? If you can tell us where exactly it is failing it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: You need to indicate where in the code is the Exception thrown.

Comment: I do not understand your code opzioni[i] would be one char what are you stepping through in your second for loop?

Comment: @N4TKD He's copying everything from before the `-` into a new char array.  Very inefficiently.

Comment: @Russell Uhi ok so he may want to search substring or split and avoid this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put a check to see if the string value is null or empty before trying to loop through each character, like this:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(opzioni))
{
    // Put loop through character logic here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to debug through and find out if your `opzioni` string is a null reference after your call to `String opzioni = lettore_file.ReadLine();`

Also, you should probably declare i within the for loop, instead of before it, like shown below.

`for (int i = 0; i < opzioni.Length; i++)`

Comment: clarification for maxpesa: declaring `i` inside the loop is not necessary, although it is considered "normal" practice, as not only is the variable destroyed upon exit of the loop, but it also looks nice too

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to say that was causing a problem, but wanted to point it out as something that is atypical.

Comment: yup!  and I agree.  I just didn't want there to be any confusion.

Comment: @uhi did you mean (int i=0;i<....)?
if yes, i put it outside the loop because i thought it was the origin of the problem

Answer (score 1):

There are several wrongs inside that code:

You're missing a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

You're not checking the result of [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx).

It looks like you're reimplementing [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx).

Sample:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\ESC\Impostazioni.txt"))
{
    using (var letterFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\ESC\Impostazioni.txt"))
    {
        var opzioni = letterFile.ReadLine();

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(opzioni))
        {
            // end of file
        }

        var dashIndex = opzioni.IndexOf("-");

        string coloregenerale = dashIndex > -1
                                    ? opzioni.Substring(0, dashIndex)
                                    : opzioni;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your null reference exception is occurring on the indicated line, the culprit is probably the opzioni variable. If the earlier call to lettore_file.ReadLine() returns null, opzioni will be null when you try to get it's length in the for loop. That will throw the exception you're experiencing. A solution is to check that variable for null before entering the loop

Answer (score 0):

The opzioni may have the chances of `null` value on that particular index, better handle inside of that line with `IsNullorEmpty` Condition

```
char[] coloregenerale = new char[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
              {
                if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(opzioni[j] == false ) // This is mandatory check at this place
                coloregenerale[j] = opzioni[j];
              }
```